# How can I make a code that uses a recursion and a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

[I did a little test to see how could it work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifFnp.jpg) I'm getting started in IDLE Python, so I basically have to write a function that takes an integer and returns a tuple that has the following form:

Detects the number of digits between 0 and 4 and also detects the number of digits between 5 and 9. And is it possible to do it with recursion? I tried everything I could think of, but it always had an error. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code that you've tried?

Comment: Yes, it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
    def cnt(n, res = (0,0)):
        if n == 0:
            return res
    
        q = n % 10
        if q <= 4:
            res = tuple([res[0] + 1, res[1]])
        else:
            res = tuple([res[0], res[1] + 1])
    
        return cnt(n//10, res)

print(cnt(12456319))
```

Output: (5, 3)